# How to Log Full Stack Trace with Winston 3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

My logger is set up like:

```
const myFormat = printf(info => {
   return `${info.timestamp}: ${info.level}: ${info.message}: ${info.err}`;
 });


 const logger =
   winston.createLogger({
   level: "info",
   format: combine(timestamp(), myFormat),

   transports: [
     new winston.transports.File({
     filename:
      "./logger/error.log",
        level: "error"
    }),
     new winston.transports.File({
       filename:
       "./logger/info.log",
       level: "info"
   })
  ]
})
```

Then I am logging out some error like this:

```
logger.error(`GET on /history`, { err });
```

How is it possible to log the full stack trace for errors to via the error transport? I tried passing in the err.stack and it came out as undefined.

Thanks !

Answer (score 45):

For winston version `3.2.0+`, following will add stacktrace to log output:

```
import { createLogger, format, transports } from 'winston';

const { combine, timestamp, prettyPrint, colorize, errors,  } = format;


const logger = createLogger({
  format: combine(
    errors({ stack: true }), // <-- use errors format
    colorize(),
    timestamp(),
    prettyPrint()
  ),
  transports: [new transports.Console()],
});
```

Ref: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1338#issuecomment-482784056

Comment: If you're using typescript replace = format by winston.format.

Comment: winston is using json in console, so `colorize()` is going to be like `level: '\x1B[31merror\x1B[39m'` lol

Answer (score 21):

You can write a formatter to pass `error.stack` to log.

```
const errorStackFormat = winston.format(info => {
  if (info instanceof Error) {
    return Object.assign({}, info, {
      stack: info.stack,
      message: info.message
    })
  }
  return info
})

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [ ... ],
  format: winston.format.combine(errorStackFormat(), myFormat)
})

logger.info(new Error('yo')) // => {message: 'yo', stack: "Error blut at xxx.js:xx ......"}
```

(the output will depend on your configuration)

Comment: What is `myFormat`?

Comment: What if we need to log a message followed by an error (similar to Java's log4j etc): `logger.error('Failed to do sth', e)`?

Answer (score 13):

Here is another take for Winston 3.2.

Nowadays Winston comes with a built-in stacktrace formatter, but it does not seem to trigger if the same formatter has `winston.format.simple()` combined. Thus, you need use `winston.format.printf` instead as by the answer from Kirai Mali. I could not figure out how to configure both `winston.format.errors()` and `winston.format.simple()` in the same configuration.

Based on the current Winston README example and answers above, here is my configuration that uses JSON format logfiles, but for the local development console it still gives colored log lines and good stack traces.

```
// Use JSON logging for log files
// Here winston.format.errors() just seem to work
// because there is no winston.format.simple()
const jsonLogFileFormat = winston.format.combine(
  winston.format.errors({ stack: true }),
  winston.format.timestamp(),
  winston.format.prettyPrint(),
);

// Create file loggers
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'debug',
  format: jsonLogFileFormat,
  transports: [
    //
    // - Write to all logs with level `info` and below to `combined.log`
    // - Write all logs error (and below) to `error.log`.
    //
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'error.log', level: 'error' }),
    new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' })
  ],
  expressFormat: true,
});

// When running locally, write everything to the console
// with proper stacktraces enabled
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  logger.add(new winston.transports.Console({
    format:  winston.format.combine(
                winston.format.errors({ stack: true }),
                winston.format.colorize(),
                winston.format.printf(({ level, message, timestamp, stack }) => {
                  if (stack) {
                      // print log trace
                      return `${timestamp} ${level}: ${message} - ${stack}`;
                  }
                  return `${timestamp} ${level}: ${message}`;
              }),
            )
  }));
}
```

Comment: Please note that: `The prettyPrint format should not be used in production because it may impact performance negatively and block the event loop.` https://github.com/winstonjs/logform#prettyprint

Answer (score 12):

**UPDATE 1/14/2021** - This no longer works in newer versions of Winston.

## *Original Answer*

@Ming's answer got me partly there, but to have a string description with the error, this is how I got full stack tracing working on ours:

```
import winston from "winston";

const errorStackTracerFormat = winston.format(info => {
    if (info.meta && info.meta instanceof Error) {
        info.message = `${info.message} ${info.meta.stack}`;
    }
    return info;
});

const logger = winston.createLogger({
    format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.splat(), // Necessary to produce the 'meta' property
        errorStackTracerFormat(),
        winston.format.simple()
    )
});

logger.error("Does this work?", new Error("Yup!"));

// The log output:
//   error: Does this work? Error: Yup!
//       at Object.<anonymous> (/path/to/file.ts:18:33)
//       at ...
//       at ...
```

Comment: I notice this is work but where is the doc saying need to put the Error object in 2nd argument?

Comment: @5413668060 You're not *supposed* to put the error object in the 2nd arg. That's for [meta data](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston#profiling). If you pass the error object as the first arg, then you'd have to change the `info.meta.XXX` references in the `errorStackTracerFormat` function to `info.XXX`

Comment: Sorry, but your example does not do what it claims to.

Comment: Yes, a console.dir of the info object does not show any meta. It instead shows some splat symbols. The internals must have changed.

Answer (score 7):

Here is my logger configuration. Added `errors({ stack: true })`, thanks to [Murli Prajapati ans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58475687/11286367) and small trick in printf function. My winston version is `3.2.1`.

```
const {format, transports} = require('winston');
const { timestamp, colorize, printf, errors } = format;
const { Console, File } = transports;
LoggerConfig = {
        level: process.env.LOGGER_LEVEL || 'debug',
        transports: [
            new Console(),
            new File({filename: 'application.log'})
        ],
        format: format.combine(
            errors({ stack: true }),
            timestamp(),
            colorize(),
            printf(({ level, message, timestamp, stack }) => {
                if (stack) {
                    // print log trace 
                    return `${timestamp} ${level}: ${message} - ${stack}`;
                }
                return `${timestamp} ${level}: ${message}`;
            }),
        ),
        expressFormat: true, // Use the default Express/morgan request formatting. Enabling this will override any msg if true. Will only output colors with colorize set to true
        colorize: false, // Color the text and status code, using the Express/morgan color palette (text: gray, status: default green, 3XX cyan, 4XX yellow, 5XX red).
        ignoreRoute: function (req, res) {
            return false;
        } // optional: allows to skip some log messages based on request and/or response
}
```

I am using this same configuration in `express-winston` and for general log also.

```
const winston = require('winston');
const expressWinston = require('express-winston');

/**
 * winston.Logger
 * logger for specified log message like console.log
 */
global.__logger = winston.createLogger(LoggerConfig);
/**
 * logger for every HTTP request comes to app
 */
app.use(expressWinston.logger(LoggerConfig));
```

Comment: Nice. It only prints API-related info that too after executing the API. How to change the priority of the middileware?

Answer (score 4):

Here is my `logger.js` with `winston": "^3.1.0`

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, timestamp, printf, colorize, splat } = format;

const myFormat = printf((info) => {
  if (info.meta && info.meta instanceof Error) {
    return `${info.timestamp} ${info.level} ${info.message} : ${info.meta.stack}`;
  }
  return `${info.timestamp} ${info.level}: ${info.message}`;
});

const LOG_LEVEL = process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'debug';
const logger = createLogger({
  transports: [
    new (transports.Console)(
      {
        level: LOG_LEVEL,
        format: combine(
          colorize(),
          timestamp(),
          splat(),
          myFormat
        )
      }
    )
  ]
});
module.exports = logger;
```

Answer (score 0):

For me to get the stack trace with winston I had to use the following logger:

```
 winston.createLogger({
    level: 'debug',
    format: winston.format.combine(
      winston.format.errors({ stack: true }),
      winston.format.metadata(),
    ),
    transports: new winston.transports.Console(),
  }),
```

Then you can add the following to make it look better:

```
      winston.format.timestamp(),
      winston.format.prettyPrint(),
```

Note that it wasn't enough for me to add **format.errors**, i also needed **format.metadata**